# Multiple column comparison perl

Tags: perl

I'm working on removing matching data from 2 files that are formatted as such :

```
scaffold_1  21786   .   A   G   198 .   DP=44;VDB=0.0402;AF1=1
```

What I am trying to do is to check these 2 files against each other for columns 1-5 (`scaffold_1` through `G` in this case). If all of these match, then I want to skip the lines, but if I have a mismatch within these 5 then they would go to their own write files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#bothfixed.pl 
use strict; use warnings; 

die "usage <file1> <file2> <write1> <write2>\n" unless @ARGV ==4; 

open (my $file1, "<", "$ARGV[0]") or die "Can't open $file1:$!";
open (my $file2, "<", "$ARGV[1]") or die "Can't open $file1:$!"; 
open (my $write1, ">", "$ARGV[2]");
open (my $write2, ">", "$ARGV[3]"); 


my $line1;  
my $line2; 
my @array1; 
my @array2; 
while (not eof $file1 && not eof $file2) {
    $line1 = <$file1> ;$line2 = <$file2>;  #print $line1; 

    @array1 = split (/\t/, $line1); 
    my @slice1 = @array1[0..4];

    @array2 = split (/\t/, $line2); 
    my @slice2 = @array2[0..4];

    my $string1 = join ('',@slice1);
    my $string2 = join ('',@slice2); 

    if ($string1 eq $string2) {next}
    else {print $write1 "$line1" ; print $write2 "$line2"}  
}
```

I only see one line removed in this process, and I think that means something's wrong with my while loop, but that's about as good a guess as I have.

Any ideas?

I've added some test data.

**Lines from file 1.**

```
scaffold_1  721 .   T   C   222 .   DP=67;VDB=0.0411;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,30,33;MQ=60;FQ=-217    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:255,190,0:63:99

scaffold_1  1282    .   T   G   36  .   DP=67;VDB=0.0396;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=23,23,15,5;MQ=26;FQ=39;PV4=0.1,0.097,0.039,1 GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:66,0,255:66:69

scaffold_1  15917   .   AATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATAT   AATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATAT 127 .   INDEL;DP=71;VDB=0.0387;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=3,13,5,6;MQ=57;FQ=130;PV4=0.21,1,0.21,1    GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:165,0,255:27:99

scaffold_1  19183   .   TAC TACAC   217 .   INDEL;DP=83;VDB=0.0408;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=24,18,16,19;MQ=60;FQ=217;PV4=0.36,1,1,0.0074   GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:255,0,255:77:99

scaffold_1  21786   .   A   G   198 .   DP=44;VDB=0.0402;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,21,22;MQ=60;FQ=-156    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:231,129,0:43:99

scaffold_1  26031   .   G   A   169 .   DP=83;VDB=0.0263;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=23,14,21,24;MQ=60;FQ=172;PV4=0.19,6.7e-28,1,1    GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:199,0,255:82:99

scaffold_1  33033   .   A   T   206 .   DP=61;VDB=0.0411;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=17,22,13,8;MQ=60;FQ=209;PV4=0.28,3.4e-05,1,1 GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:236,0,255:60:99

scaffold_1  33799   .   C   A   146 .   DP=56;VDB=0.0394;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=13,14,13,14;MQ=60;FQ=149;PV4=1,6.2e-28,0.16,0.14 GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:176,0,255:54:99

scaffold_1  35051   .   CAAAAAAAAAA CAAAAAAAAAAA    32.5    .   INDEL;DP=51;VDB=0.0447;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=1,1,22,13;MQ=60;FQ=-118;PV4=1,1,1,1  GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:73,83,0:37:99
```

**Lines from file 2**

```
scaffold_1  721 .   T   C   221 .   DP=57;VDB=0.0407;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,23,32;MQ=60;FQ=-193    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:254,166,0:55:99

scaffold_1  1282    .   T   G   80  .   DP=82;VDB=0.0383;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=29,30,13,9;MQ=26;FQ=83;PV4=0.46,0.19,0.5,1   GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:110,0,238:81:99

scaffold_1  10472   .   A   C   23  .   DP=44;VDB=0.0402;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=6,8,1,11;MQ=60;FQ=26;PV4=0.081,9.7e-12,1,1   GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:53,0,246:26:56

scaffold_1  15917   .   AATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATAT   AATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATATAT 186 .   INDEL;DP=39;VDB=0.0416;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=5,6,5,5;MQ=60;FQ=189;PV4=1,1,1,0.43    GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:224,0,237:21:99

scaffold_1  19183   .   TAC TACAC   217 .   INDEL;DP=76;VDB=0.0383;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=16,12,20,23;MQ=60;FQ=217;PV4=0.47,1,1,0.11 GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:255,0,255:71:99
scaffold_1  21786   .   A   G   196 .   DP=58;VDB=0.0365;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,33,24;MQ=60;FQ=-199    GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:229,172,0:57:99

scaffold_1  26031   .   G   A   169 .   DP=70;VDB=0.0407;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=13,12,22,23;MQ=60;FQ=172;PV4=1,6.1e-26,1,1   GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:199,0,255:70:99

scaffold_1  33033   .   A   T   225 .   DP=41;VDB=0.0404;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=8,9,13,10;MQ=60;FQ=225;PV4=0.75,0.0052,1,1   GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:255,0,255:40:99

scaffold_1  33799   .   C   A   116 .   DP=61;VDB=0.0410;AF1=0.5;AC1=1;DP4=18,20,11,12;MQ=60;FQ=119;PV4=1,3.6e-28,1,0.46    GT:PL:DP:GQ 0/1:146,0,255:61:99
scaffold_1  35051   .   CAAAAAAAAAA CAAAAAAAAAAA,CAAAAAAAAAAAA  47.5    .   INDEL;DP=40;VDB=0.0384;AF1=1;AC1=2;DP4=0,0,16,17;MQ=60;FQ=-128  GT:PL:DP:GQ 1/1:88,93,0,82,60,76:33:99
```

Comment: If all 5 comparisons must be true, you can't print after each single check, you must do all tests at once. If you are looking for string equality, you might as well capture the first 5 columns in one string and compare those.

Comment: I've edited the code to match what you described (I think) but I still get the same problems.

Comment: Why do you discard every other line? (in the last paragraph)

Comment: I think that was a mistake in copy/pasting the code! I'll remove it.

Comment: You should use `or die "Cannot open $file: $!"` with your open statements. Otherwise you will have a silent error if one of the opens fails (because `while (not eof ...)` does not warn about reading from non-open files)

Comment: You should also as a rule of thumb use `and` instead of `&&` (and `or` over `||`), because `and` has lower precedence, and is more likely to do what you expect. For example, this is wrong: `open my $fh, "<", $file || die`, because it is equivalent to `open my $fh, "<", ($file || die)` -- which will never fail unless `$file` is the empty string or zero.

Comment: If you supply us with test data to run your script, we might be able to figure out why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Are you wanting to compare the lines as they appear, or do you actually want to compare the entries for each number in col 2? e.g. file 2 has a line starting `scaffold_1  10472...` which is missing from file 1, and hence everything in file 1 is off by two lines.

Comment: I agree, the comparison method seems broken. What is your expected output from the two sample files? What is the real intent with the comparison? Also, if this is bioperl, you should check if there is a module written already that can do this for you. Check for example https://metacpan.org/search?q=bioperl

Comment: What I am trying to do is get unique data from files that represent two populations.  Ideally, this would print out only the `10472` line, but I think I understand what you're saying --- line by line comparison might not be the way to go. I think I will rework this using hashes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. You need to slurp the first file into memory and store it in a hash indexed with the `$string1` comparison string, and then you can check for each line in the second file whether we've seen it before. This code will shuffle the output lines in the first file; if you need to keep them ordered you can add another hash to save the line number, and sort the final output loop using that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#bothfixed.pl 
use strict; use warnings; 

die "usage <file1> <file2> <write1> <write2>\n" unless @ARGV ==4; 

open (my $file1, "<", "$ARGV[0]") or die "Can't open $file1:$!";
open (my $file2, "<", "$ARGV[1]") or die "Can't open $file1:$!"; 
open (my $write1, ">", "$ARGV[2]");
open (my $write2, ">", "$ARGV[3]"); 


my $line1;  
my $line2; 
my @array1; 
my @array2;
my %file1;
my %match;

# Slurp first file into memory
while ( $line1 = <file1> ) {
    @array1 = split (/\t/, $line1); 
    my @slice1 = @array1[0..4];
    my $string1 = join ('',@slice1);
    $file1{$string1} = $line1;
}

# Run through second file
while ($line2 = <$file2>) {
    @array2 = split (/\t/, $line2); 
    my @slice2 = @array2[0..4];
    my $string2 = join ('',@slice2); 

    if ($file1{$string2}) {
        # If we've matched then we wont want to print it out at the end
        $match{$string2}++;
    } else {
        print $write2 "$line2";
    }  
}

foreach my $string1 (keys %file1) {
    next if $match{$string1};
    print $write1 "$line1";
}
```